# Why does zsh replace hyphens with underscores in these functions?

Tags: zsh, function

I've got the following function aliases sourced in zsh and bash consoles:

```
compose() {
  docker-compose $*
}

run() {
  compose "run --rm app $*"
}

rails() {
  run "rails $*"
}
```

In bash, running `rails c` starts a Ruby on Rails console through docker-compose successfully.

In zsh, running `rails c` results in a command not found error where the hyphens are replaced by underscores:

```
➜ rails c
No such command: run __rm app rails c
```

My zsh version:

```
➜ zsh --version
zsh 5.6.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `zsh` that's replacing dashes with underscores, but probably that `docker-compose` program, or another program called by it.

The problem is that `zsh`, unlike `bash`, does not split unquoted variables with `IFS` by default.

If I define `docker-compose` as a function that prints each of its argument surrounded by `{}`, this is what I obtain:

```
$ cat example
docker-compose() {
        echo -n docker-compose
        for f in "$@"; do echo -n " {$f}"; done; echo
}
compose() { docker-compose $*; }
run() { compose "run --rm app $*"; }
rails() { run "rails $*"; }   
rails c

$ zsh example
docker-compose {run --rm app rails c}

$ bash example
docker-compose {run} {--rm} {app} {rails} {c}
```

Notice how `run`, `--rm`, `app`, etc. are passed as separate arguments in `bash` and as a single argument in `zsh`.

That's because `bash` did split and trim the `$*` variable into multiple arguments using spaces (the default value of `IFS`) as the delimiter. The same effect could be obtained in `zsh` by using `$=*` instead of `$*`, or by the `set -o SH_WORD_SPLIT` option, but that will make the script zsh-only.

You should use `"$@"` instead of `$*` everywhere, unless you have some very special reason not to:

```
compose() { docker-compose "$@"; }
run() { compose run --rm app "$@"; }
rails() { run rails "$@"; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great example script! I'm confused if you are recommending using `$=*` or `"$@"`. I had already tried the latter though and it didn't seem to make a difference. I'll try `$=*`.

Comment: I do **not** recommend using `$=* ` or other zsh-specific features. I've only added it for completeness' sake. The example at the end of my answer uses `"$@"` and works the same in any shell, and the same as your example in `bash`. Notice that the quotes in `run()` and `rails()` are only around `"$@"`.

Comment: Moving the quotes around only the `"$@"` did the trick! Thanks.