# ZSH macro for docker-compose substitutes - for _

Tags: zsh, docker-compose

I'm using zsh which I understand is different to bash, but mostly similar. I decided to make a macro for my docker-compose command:

```
dock-comp() {
   state="$2"
   if [ "$state" = "up" ]; then
      state='up -d'
   fi

   # For debugging
   echo "docker-compose -p $1 -f my/path/to/file.yml "$(echo "$state")""

   # The actual command that runs
   docker-compose -p $1 -f my/path/to/file.yml "$(echo "$state")"
}
```

So if I run `dock-comp CONTAINER down` that works fine, but I get issues with `dock-comp CONTAINER up`. You can see if I enter `up` it should append the `-d` and the echo print confirms that this becomes what I want, but then the command gives the following output:

```
> dock-comp CONTAINER up            
docker-compose -p CONTAINER -f my/path/to/file.yml up -d
No such command: up _d

Commands:
  build              Build or rebuild services
(etc)
```

[This is the closest post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477077/why-does-zsh-replace-hyphens-with-underscores-in-these-functions) I can find to my issue, but I don't think its that relevant since I'm not using the same arguments thing and my echo proves it *should* be processed right, but bash is weird so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't know zsh, but for bash you would try "bash -x your_script and parameters" to see what is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the quotes, `docker-compose` sees `up -d` as a single command, not as `up` with a `-d` option. Presumably its parsing then replaces `-` with `_`, but it’s too late anyway.

Dropping the quotes and the unnecessary `echo` and changing `state` to an array (since it can contain multiple parameters) fixes things:

```
dock-comp() {
   state=($2)
   if [[ $state[1] == up ]]; then
      state+=(-d)
   fi
   docker-compose -p "$1" -f my/path/to/file.yml $state
}
```

Comment: I see, I assumed when the command ran it would re-parse the string, but now that I'm thinking about it, that's no a good idea since there are cases where you want to preserve the whitespace in the strings. And yeah the echo was from a leftover debugging shot.